# UIScrollView not scrolling all the way

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I have programmed a UIScrollView to scroll 320x800 however it stops scrolling a certain way down, even if I change the size in code it still stops scrolling the same way down, my only idea is the view is 548px in height. Here is the code I currently have in 'ViewController.m'.

```
[ScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

This code currently holds in `- (void)viewDidLoad`. All the links are made in Interface Builder and I get no errors while compiling. Just thought I should say I'm in Xcode 4.5.2.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I should say that the `UIScrollView` still scrolls but only some way.

Comment: what is the scrollview frame size??

Comment: Set your `contentSize` larger, as that is what allows the `scrollview` to scroll.

Comment: @R.A My frame in Interface Builder is `320 width` and `548 height`.

Comment: how far down is it scrolling.  how do you know it isn't 800px?

Comment: @danh I use Interface Builder to change it to 320x800 and put a label at the bottom then change it back and centre it, when I scroll I don't see the label.

Comment: I'd place my suspicion there.  Will give some debug advice in answer...

Answer (score 0):

You get a clearer picture of what's wrong by trying the following...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];  // consider renaming to lowercase 'scrollView'

    for (int i = 50; i < 800; i += 50) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, i, 100, 22)];
        label.text = [NSString string withFormat:@"label at y=%d", i];
        [ScrollView addSubview:label];
    }
}
```

Note that the loop ends at 750, so that's the last label you should see.